# How to access a url and get its response from java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to servlet programming my task is to write a srvlet program that will access a url and retrieve its contents .pls do help

Comment: You should be able to take advantage of the [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and it's associated [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to read the contents. You might like to provide some more details about what it is you're trying to do, as I'm not entirely sure this will meet your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;


public class URLServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        URL urldemo = new URL("http://www.demo.com/");
        URLConnection yc = urldemo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();

    }
}
```

Plain java Program

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class URLServlet {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        try {
        URL urldemo = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        URLConnection yc = urldemo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul i tried ur code but each time i try to connect i get a connection refused error ! i tried connecting to www.google.com

Comment: It is working at my end. I have tried using simple java program, code attached above

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a basic question regarding Servlets. In SO we have special places that such basic questions are answered. Just click the `servlet` tag on your right and then select the `info` tab in your top left. Or visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info .

There is a basic example there on how you can use servlets.