# java unknown host exception not able to ressolve

Tags: java

I Wanted to download one zip file from one URL, for that I Used the below code to open an URL and download one zip file from .But what happens is I am getting following exception

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.abc.com
```

So I just did some reasearch and guessed that could be the problem of certficate
and generated the certificate by using below keytool command

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

After that I set the location of generated keystore.jks file by using the following
code

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Programme\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_31\\jre\\bin\\keystore.jks");
```

After running the code, still I am getting the same exception

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.abc.com
```

Any idea how to ressolve? I am able to access this site from the Browser.

My full code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class UrlDownload {
    final static int size = 1024;

    public static void fileUrl(String fAddress, String localFileName,
            String destinationDir) {
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        URLConnection uCon = null;

        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URL Url;
            byte[] buf;
            int ByteRead, ByteWritten = 0;
            Url = new URL(fAddress);
            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    destinationDir + "\\" + localFileName));

            uCon = Url.openConnection();
            is = uCon.getInputStream();
            buf = new byte[size];
            while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
                ByteWritten += ByteRead;
            }
            System.out.println("Downloaded Successfully.");
            System.out.println("File name:\"" + localFileName
                    + "\"\nNo ofbytes :" + ByteWritten);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void fileDownload(String fAddress, String destinationDir) {
        int slashIndex = fAddress.lastIndexOf('/');
        int periodIndex = fAddress.lastIndexOf('.');

        String fileName = fAddress.substring(slashIndex + 1);

        if (periodIndex >= 1 && slashIndex >= 0
                && slashIndex < fAddress.length() - 1) {
            fileUrl(fAddress, fileName, destinationDir);
        } else {
            System.err.println("path or file name.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "http://www.abc.com/coolsolutions/tools/downloads/ntradping.zip";
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Programme\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_31\\jre\\bin\\keystore.jks");
            String destAddress = "C:\\downloads";
                fileDownload(url,destAddress);

        } 
    }
```

I tried the below code. That throws unknown host exception.

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.google.com");
    String ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString()'
    System.out.println(ipAddress );
```

Comment: Well UnknownHostException is quite specific. Are you sure that your computer can reach that host? Ever tried to do a nslookup on that? By the way: using a self signed certificate in your trust store would not help with the connection at all as the remote host probably would not trust your certificate for establishing the connection.

Comment: Is this website your own, I mean hosted on your local system ?. Java docs for UnknownHostException says "Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined."

Comment: Your code should work correctly. I've tried to download the file that was in your source but it was not found (try to replace it with: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/DirectoryStructure.gif) and it will work. Another thing that I suggest is to use `try` with resource (that is if you are using JDK 7) - that will eliminate the need for `finally`.

Comment: I have tried this code from my office. Not from home. so any possibility that I have to do something else in my proxy or anything like that to make if work? I am able to access that particular url through Browser and download zip file from there. But When it comes to java code, I get this exception.

Comment: For me the URL : accessing the [zip-url](http://www.abc.com/coolsolutions/tools/downloads/ntradping.zip) redirects to another [page](http://abc.go.com/coolsolutions/tools/downloads/ntradping.zip?nord=2) with the message that the page was not found. Is any authentication required to fetch the same?

Comment: that abc.com is a fake one. I did not add the right one.www.novell.com is the actuall one

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: What happens when you ping the site? And what is the DNS server that is in use (use `nslookup <your site>`)?

Comment: DNS server company dns server name and ip address dns-it.abc.def

Comment: Try using an IP address instead of the host name. Try `http://173.194.78.147/images/google_favicon_128.png`

Comment: I tried passing the IP address. java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems to me like a firewall issue...

Comment: Even I felt about the same. I am running in Eclipse. in Eclipse there is one preference section,there do I need to anything with? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this Exception according to javadocs is, Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined. So check the fAddress String.

try passing "http://www.novell.com/home/" in your fAddress variable insteat "www.novell.com"

Hope it helps..

Comment: I tried that one as well. it was not working. Also I have written 'InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.google.com")'; which also causes the same unknown exception. This I tried to check my system configuration whether I can access any external site through java code. I think it is the problem of my system setting. Not able to access external url thorugh java code. Any idea how to make it work? Any proxy or host file change or something like that?

Comment: look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634213/how-to-access-a-url-and-get-its-response-from-java-servlet